# Some call graphs missing in C

Tags: doxygen, call-graph, aliases

I have a function `Process1` for which I want to generate a call graph:

```
/**
********************************************************************************
\file             test.c
********************************************************************************
*/

/* function prototypes */
void Process1(void);
void init_function1 (void);
void function1 (void);
void function2 (void);


/**
********************************************************************************
\project          projectx
\funcname         Process1
\details          Aufruf von Prozess 1
                  \callgraph
********************************************************************************
*/
void Process1 (void)
{
    init_function1();
        for (;;)
    {
        function1();
        function2();
    }
}

/**
********************************************************************************
\details          Aufruf von Init Funktion 1
********************************************************************************
*/
void init_function1 (void)
{
    ;
}

/**
********************************************************************************
\details          Aufruf von Funktion 1
********************************************************************************
*/
void function1 (void)
{
    ;
}

/**
********************************************************************************
\details          Aufruf von Funktion 2
********************************************************************************
*/
void function2 (void)
{
    ;
}
```

The keywords `\project` and `\funcname` are ALIASES defined in Doxygen GUI 1.8.14 (Windows 7) to get a similar format like e.g. `\author` The definition is like that:

```
funcname=\par Name ^^
project=\par Project ^^
```

My problem is that if I use the ALIASES there is no callgraph. If I do not use the ALIASES (remove them in source code) there is a callgraph. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have any settings in your Doxyfile that differs from the standard Doxyfile (e.g. `HAVE_DOT=YES`) as when I set `HAVE_DOT` to `YES` the call graph is shown.

Comment: Maybe also a good idea to replace `funcname=\par Name ^^` by `"funcname=\par Name ^^"` and analogous for project

Comment: The differences to standard settings are:

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = NO
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = NO
DOT_PATH               = "../../../../Program Files (x86)/Graphviz/release/bin"

Comment: The definition of ALIASES was made with Doxygen GUI. So in Doxyfile it appears like you stated:
ALIASES                = "funcname=\par Name ^^" \
                         "project=\par Project ^^"

Comment: Don't know why but now I can reproduce the problem as well, only relevant setting is the HAVE_DOT (and the ALIAS and when dot is not in the path the DOT_PATH). When possible please create an issue in the doxygen issue tacker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new) with attached a, small, self contained example (source+config file in a tar or zip; no references to external sources please) that allows us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanky for your reply. I have created an issue: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6547